# Will the Logitech Couch Mouse work?

Tags: hardware, mouse, compatibility

Will the [Logitech Couch Mouse](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/mice-pointers/mice/devices/7759) work out-of-the-box on Ubuntu? Or do I need to install drivers? They fully support Windows and Mac, but don't say anything about Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell you for sure, but it's highly likely it will work with no difficulties. Mouses aren't particularly complicated beasts!

(I have a Logitech mouse/keyboard wireless set that works perfectly)